# How do we make sure the record is being locked?

Tags: plsql, interface, data-conversion, oracle-ebs

In Oracle EBS, when we are doing data conversions and interfaces, loading data into Oracle from another system, how do we make sure the record is being locked?  How do we make sure no other person is updating our records?

Comment: Are you loading into a production system? If so, I recommend loading during off-hours with the application not running. if you are using a CP to load then again off-hours and ensure that no other user is using the system during the load.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle EBS seeded API's will take care about locking. We don't insert data into EBS base tables directly, 
validate the data and insert into interface tables later we run oracle standard programs to import interface tables data into base tables. 
These oracle standard programs use oracle seeded API to insert data into multiple base tables.

How do we make sure no other person is updating our records?

Developers use their own custom staging tables to import data into EBS.
when data upload staging tables to interface table maintain each interface data source is different, usually other persons don't update other interfaces records, We can't track if anyone updated from database backend tools like sql developer or TOAD. we can track transaction from last updated by column if they update from applications

If you have any specific issue related locking let us know